# How to associate registry with scope in Yarn 2 without breaking auth?

Tags: security, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

[This article](https://github.blog/2021-02-12-avoiding-npm-substitution-attacks/#why-and-how-to-use-scopes) suggests adding configuration to `.npmrc` in your project to associate a scope with a private registry to reduce the risk of a npm substitution attack (where someone might deliberately publish a malicious public package with the same name).

How can we achieve a similar effect in a Yarn 2 project? I've tried adding a `.yarnrc.yml` file in my project root:

```
npmScopes:
  someScope:
    npmRegistryServer: https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

We also have a home-directory `~/.yarnrc.yml` for each developer with similar configuration, but additionally with an appropriate `npmAuthToken` to authenticate.

However, when I do a `yarn install`, I get an `Invalid authentication (as an anonymous user)` error for packages in that scope. Presumably the project-specific `.yarnrc.yml` is overriding the settings from the per-user `~/.yarnrc.yml`, so the auth information is no longer present?

The mitigation I'm after is that if a developer forgets to run `yarn npm login`, then it won't check the public registry for packages in a particular scope. Is there a way to do this in Yarn 2?

Answer (score 3):

As @R.Hagl mentioned, the configurations are not merged but replaced. This is meant to be [fixed](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/4341#issuecomment-1222197137) in the next major release of yarn (4?).

At the moment to get it working, you have to put the full configuration into the **global** `~/.yarnrc.yml`:

```
npmScopes:
  someScope:
    npmRegistryServer: https://npm.pkg.github.com
    npmAuthToken: <your-token>
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
```

or if you use credentials, omit the `npmAuthToken` and use `yarn npm login --scope someScope`. This will add the token to the global file.

You have to completely remove npmScopes from the project's `yarnrc.yml`. Because the local file takes precedence and if the section (`npmScopes`) is found, it replaces the same section from the global file. As the token is stored in the global file (to avoid committing it to the repo), the authentication fails as it is never supplied.

**UPDATE**

Configuration merging should now be fixed as per https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/pull/4982. Doesn't seem to be released yet though. As per comments below, it might be considered a breaking change and only released in version 4.

Comment: Just tried with 3.3.0 and it seems the issue still exists :( Workaround continues to be valid

Comment: I also tried it and it's not available yet. The changelog for 3.3.0 does not include the linked PR. From the conversations in the linked PR it seems like they're releasing this feature as part of yarn 4. https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/pull/4982#issuecomment-1297253438

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I did not check the change log, I've somehow automatically supposed that it was merged there. Updated the update :-)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. The problem is that you have to define the authentication per section (like pointed out in this [issue comment](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/2106#issuecomment-724995773)). This also applies to `npmRegistries`.

```
npmScopes:
  someScope:
    npmRegistryServer: <your-registry-server>
    npmAuthToken: <your-token>
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
```

Mind that duplicated configurations in hierarchical definitions of `.yarnrc.yml` won't be merged but replaced ([see this comment](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/1319#issuecomment-625552162)). Thus, if `npmScopes` is already declared in the home directory it is overwritten by the declaration in the project.